# c# перекрывание членов родительского класа

Tags: c#, наследование

Имеется три класса :

```
class a
{
 protected int number = 10;
}

class b:a
{
new private int number = 9000; //переменая а - private
}

class c:b 
{
  public int showValue()
   {
    return this.number;
   }

}
```

В функции main()

```
 Console.WriteLine(new c().showValue());
```

По логике, после перекрытия атрибута number в классе b, этот атрибут является уже не унаследованым от класа а, а сообственым, и при попытке вызвать функцию showValue() класом с компилятор должен выдать ошику. Но вместо этого, компилятор благополучно выводит значения number = 10. Повторюсь, атрибут number в класе b являеться не унаследованым, а сообственым (или я чего-то не знаю и ошибаюсь). Так почему тогда выводиться 10 вместо сообщения об ошибке, что мы пытаемся обратиться с другого класа к private атрибуту?

Comment: А вы попробуйте перенести showValue на уровень класса b и сразу увидите, что используется переменная с 9000. Protected - значит будет доступен потомкам, а по какой причине private означает доступность потомкам?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В C# применяются следующие [модификаторы доступа](https://metanit.com/sharp/tutorial/3.2.php):

> - public: публичный, общедоступный класс или член класса. Такой член класса доступен из любого места в коде, а также из других программ и
>     сборок.
> - private: закрытый класс или член класса. Представляет полную противоположность модификатору public. Такой закрытый класс или член
>     класса доступен только из кода в том же классе или контексте.
> - protected: такой член класса доступен из любого места в текущем классе или в производных классах. При этом производные классы могут
>     располагаться в других сборках.

То, что вы переопередили number  в классе b - не означает что потом увидят именно это значение. Для потомков виден number с класса a.

Попробуйте вывести `Console.WriteLine(new c().showLocalValue());`

```
class b : a
{
    new private int number = 9000; //переменая а - private
    public int showLocalValue()
    {
        return this.number;
    }
}
```

И вы увидите значение 9000.

Также вы можете указать для number на классе b видимость как protected - тогда в c будет использоваться значение с b.

Answer (score 0):

В классе **b** у поля модификатор доступа private, а не public или protected. Поэтому и отображается поле класса **a**, а не **b** - у последнего оно недоступно извне.